# Install Redmine on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, redmine

I try to install Redmine 2.4.1 on Windows 7.

I follow the following steps:

1. Install RailsInstaller-Windows-2.2.1 on `C:\RailsInstaller`
2. Install ImageMagick-6.8.7-7-Q16-x64-dll on `C:\ImageMagick`

After installation I put a file called `libmySQL.dll` into `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin` and try to run the following command in `cmd.exe`

```
C:\Sites\redmine-master>gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick/include)
```

The result is:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

After I do that I try to run:

```
C:\Sites\redmine-master>gem install mysql
```

The result is:

```
You've installed the binary version of mysql.
It was built using MySQL Connector/C version 6.0.2.
It's recommended to use the exact same version to avoid potential issues.
At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files where available
in the following URL:
 http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick
You can put the lib\libmysql.dll available in this package to your Ruby bin directory.
E.g. C:\Ruby\bin
Successfully installed mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32...
```

Then I install bundler.

```
C:\Sites\redmine-master>gem install bundler
```

The result is:

```
Fetching: bundler-1.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.3.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.3.5...
```

Finally I try to run

```
rake generate_secret_token
```

The result is:

```
C:\Sites\redmine-master>rake generate_secret_token
←[31mCould not find gem 'database_cleaner (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems availa
ble on this machine.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

Please tell me how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Do you mean to run this in production or just a personal instance?

Comment: i try to run bundel install but there is something error  /// i need install redmine in windows environment and using xampp to run redmine but i can not